# Rails 3.2.6 - .js.erb does nothing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly simply demo app to learn AJAX / jQuery.

1. In assets/javascripts/runner.js I have the following code:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajaxSettings.accepts.html = $.ajaxSettings.accepts.script;

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
       url: "http://localhost:3000/home/index",
           data: { name: "John", age: "35" },
           dataType: 'html'
       });
   }
   ```
2. This correctly calls home/index, where I have the following code in the index action:

   respond_to do |format|
          format.js
      end
3. This seems to correctly call index.js.erb, where I have:

   alert("hi");
4. The problem is that the alert doesnt show up! I can see in the console of FireBug that I am getting "alert("hi")" correctly in the XHR response, but the alert doesnt execute!

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually processing the result fo your ajax call.  The returned javascript never gets evaluated by the browser.  It should be more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSettings.accepts.html = $.ajaxSettings.accepts.script;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/home/index",
        data: { name: "John", age: "35" },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            eval(data);  // where data is the javascript generated by home#index
        }
    });
}
```

Keep in mind that if someone is able to control the contents of this returned javascript, you could expose yourself to a nasty script injection vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that worked! Question though - where do the .js.erb files fit in the pipeline - what should I use those for?